# javascript refuses to work in head/external file

Tags: javascript, external, filereader, head

I'm using the following code to have a picture preview before upload. The code is working, but i want to **store the script** in an **external file** or at least in the **html-head**. I can't figure out how to do so. I think my problem is with this part, but I'm not sure at all:

```
reader.onload = (function(theFile) {...
```

Help would be appreciated :)

Here comes the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
    .thumb {
            height: 75px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
    }
</style>

</head>


<body>

<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

<script>


    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
            var files = evt.target.files;


            for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

                if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                    continue;
                }

                var reader = new FileReader();

                document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = "";


                //the problem might be caused by this ".onload" ?
                reader.onload = (function(theFile) {

                    return function(e) {

                        var span = document.createElement('span');

                        span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                                   '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/><input type="text" name="', escape(theFile.name), '-title" placeholder="title" /><input type="text" name="', escape(theFile.name), '-description" placeholder="description" />'].join('');

                        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                    };
                })(f);

            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
            }
    }

    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you know.... you can add console.log() line after each line in your script and see, if anything is happening in there and where it stops.  You should try basic debugging yourself before posting here.

Comment: There are several issues. Firstly, you are assigning the *result* of an immediate function to the onload handler. i.e. `(function test() { ... })()`.  Removing the 2 sets of outer parens will be a good start: i.e. `function test() {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:**

You just need to create a new file *e.g. "extJsFile.js"*.

**Step 2:**

Put the content in between the  tag of your question's code (I won't repeat the same code, for the sake of simplicity) and then write one line in between  tag of your html file.(Assumption -  you are putting js and html in same directory of your project)

**PS:  You should at least google before asking a question, anyway carry on with your codes...**